# How does one keep the tabkey from triggering the keyup/keydown event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I assign the desired  tags with `class='ShowSave'`, make sure the `SaveButton` container is not displayed at start up, then display the `SaveButton` container when a keyup event occurs (data entry).

Everything works fine except the tab key also triggers a keyup event causing the SaveButton container to show when no data has changed. I tried just using `$(".ShowSave").change()`, but the `SaveButton` container only displayed after I left the field. That's not desirable.

jQuery:

```
$(".SaveButton").css({'display':'none'});
$("input.ShowSave").keyup*( function(){ $(".SaveButton").css({'display':'block'}); } );
```

HTML:

```
<form>
    <td><input class='ShowSave' name="foo" type="text" value='foo' tabindex='1'></td><
    <td class='SaveButton' ><img class='SaveImage' onClick='jsPostMe()' /></td>
</form>
```

Thanks ahead of time for any advice. I'm using straight jQuery with no plug-ins.

Comment: change `.keyup*(` to `.keyup(`

Comment: Have your `keyup` handler check whether value has changed.

Answer (score 4):

You want to test for the keycode if your `keyup` event. Something like this:

```
$("input.ShowSave").keyup(function(e){
    var code = e.which;
    //keycode 9 = tab
    if(code == 9) {
       return;
    }
    //do something
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/WEGp2/1/)

This of course will mean that other keys may also be pressed that are not valid. You could also include a check for those key codes ([here is a list](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)), but it would be better if you instead tracking the original value of the textbox and then checked for a change on `keyup`.

Something like this (note: it makes use of data attributes):

```
<input data-original="old" value="old" class="ShowSave" />

$("input.ShowSave").keyup(function(e){
    var original = $(this).data("original");
    var newValue = $(this).val();

    //check if value has changed
    if(original == newValue){
        $(".SaveButton").hide();
    }
    else{
        $(".SaveButton").show();
    }
});
```

[Here is an example for this](http://jsfiddle.net/WEGp2/2/)

Comment: Why are you doing `(e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which)`? Just use `e.which` - jQuery normalizes it

Comment: @Ian, I will take your word for that. You sound like you are correct

Answer (score 2):

something like this

```
$("input.ShowSave").keyup(function(e){
    if(e.which != 9){
        $(".SaveButton").css({'display':'block'});
    }
});
```